# Out of Memory Redim vArray VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the following block of codes which searches the indicated range for text qualifiers and periods (dots). If these were found, it will be highlighted. The code ran fine if the data set is small but run into issues if the file is big. I tested it on a while with 55000 rows and it gave me a "out of memory" error. Is there any way around this? Thanks!

```
    'Check for extra text qualifiers and if there are periods
    Keywords = Array(Chr(34), "'", ",")
    CodeKeyword = Array(".")
    lastrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File").Range("A1:BH" & lastrow2)
    Set SearchRangeCode = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File").Range("O2:AM" & lastrow2)
    iRange_Col = SearchRange.Columns.Count
    iRange_Row = SearchRange.Rows.Count
    iRangeCode_Col = SearchRangeCode.Columns.Count
    iRangeCode_Row = SearchRangeCode.Rows.Count
    ReDim vArray(1 To iRange_Row, 1 To iRange_Col)
    ReDim vArrayCode(1 To iRangeCode_Row, 1 To iRangeCode_Col)
    vArray = SearchRange
    vArrayCode = SearchRangeCode
```

Comment: Can you break this up into chunks of maybe 10k rows and process each chunk in a loop?

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, do you mind showing me on how to breaking these into chunks? I am fairly new to vba..

Comment: The range `"O2:AM" & lastrow2` is *within* `"A1:BH" & lastrow2` so while it may make coding easier, you are using 40% more memory than you need to.

Comment: @Futochan - hard to write an example without knowing what you plan to do with those arrays once you have them populated.

Comment: If you use `Dim vArray As Variant` the assignment would be `vArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File").Range("A1:BH" & lastrow2)` with none of the bother in between. The array's index would be *1* based with `LBound(vArray, <first rank>)` and `UBound(vArray, <last rank>)` as extents.

Comment: @Jeeped what do I need to put for <first rank> and <last rank>? Thanks!

Comment: In this circumstance the *rank* is the same as column. If *lastrow2-* was *999* then vArray(2, 5) would be the same as E2. See [Arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) ◄ search for *rank* on the page.